# minify JS causes error related to braintree.min.js

Tags: magento2, javascript

As the subject says, Braintree payment method does not show up after minified JS. There is error

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.min.js"

Braintree.min.js does not exist but braintree.js. Does anyone have the same issue and solution for it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This issue related to an old implementation of Braintree integration.
The Magento 2.1 will be always use [the minified version](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Braintree/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js) of Braintree SDK.

You can use the Magento 2.1RC3 or latest develop branch to test it.

Related Github issues:

- [#4713](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4713)
- [#3916](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3916)
- [#4510](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4510)